# Add Sub Menu in Blogger (pageListJSON)

Tags: html, json, blogger

I want to add sub menu in my blog. I want my menu to be like this (manual testing and automated testing become the sub menu of testing)

- Testing

  - Manual Testing
  - Automated Testing

There are a lot of tutorials in the internet. However, they are still using the old blogger design where they use `<ul>` and `<li>` syntax. In the new blogger (I don't know when it starts), blogger uses JSON for page list management instead of `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Followings is the `pageListJson` from my blog:

```
<b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' title='Pages' type='PageList'>
<b:widget-settings>
  <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'>
    <![CDATA[{'91385535799150449': {'href': 'https://belajarbersama-arwan.blogspot.com/p/belajar-software-testing.html', 
            'title': 'Software Testing', 
            'position': 0}, 
    '4514379653067780013': {'href': 'https://belajarbersama-arwan.blogspot.com/p/manual-testing.html', 
            'title': 'Manual Testing', 
            'position': 1}, 
    '5318229156935072720': {'href': 'https://belajarbersama-arwan.blogspot.com/p/automated-testing.html', 
            'title': 'Automated Testing', 
            'position': 2}}]]>
    </b:widget-setting>
  <b:widget-setting name='homeTitle'>Home</b:widget-setting>
</b:widget-settings>
```

Using this JSON, the menu appears to be like this:

- Testing
- Manual Testing
- Automated Testing

I tried to modify the JSON to be like this

```
{'91385535799150449': 
    {'href': 'https://belajarbersama-arwan.blogspot.com/p/belajar-software-testing.html', 
    'title': 'Software Testing', 
    'position': 0, 
    '4514379653067780013': {'href': 'https://belajarbersama-arwan.blogspot.com/p/manual-testing.html', 
            'title': 'Manual Testing', 
            'position': 1}, 
    '5318229156935072720': {'href': 'https://belajarbersama-arwan.blogspot.com/p/automated-testing.html', 
            'title': 'Automated Testing', 
            'position': 2}}}
```

However, only one menu appear i.e. Software Testing

Can anybody help how can I modify the JSON so I can get the menu structure that I want?

Thank you for your kind helps

Answer (score 1):

PageList widget not have sub menu, json script just for settings purpose only like title, url and position, not for adding something.
You can add manually using ul and li if you want create sub menu for each list.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mainstreem. If that is the case, then I will just add it manually using `ul` and `li`.

Comment: i add `<li><ul><li>asdsad</li><li>asdsad</li><li>asdsad</li></ul></li>` for testing after </b:loop> but the layout loooks like arrrgh
the menu just arrange horizontally like normal, there is no dropdown

Comment: oh i found how to do that, just go to layout->menu widget, the add nu external link with _ as prefix menu title name